# trying to read the links from the txt file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i have saved the extracted links in the txt file and now i am trying to read the txt file and extract the scope section from the website: https://training.gov.au/Organisation/Details/31102
but i am having error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ayushnepal/PycharmProjects/training/Courses/table.py", line 36, in 
each_url.find_element_by_css_selector('a#detailsScopeTab').click()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'

code :
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import bs4 as bs4
from pathlib import Path
import os

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incognito")
option.add_argument("--headless")
exec_path = "/Users/Downloads/MUR_scraping-master/Libraries/chromedriver"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=exec_path, options=option)


course_links_file_path = Path(os.getcwd().replace('\\', '/'))
course_links_file_path = course_links_file_path.__str__() + '/links.txt'
course_links_file = open(course_links_file_path, 'r')

for each_url in course_links_file:
print(each_url)
try:
    browser.get(each_url)
except:
    print(each_url)
    pass
pure_url = each_url.strip()
each_url = browser.page_source
delay_ = 15
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(each_url, 'lxml')


browser.get("https://training.gov.au/Organisation/Details/31102")

# open the scope tab
each_url.find_element_by_css_selector('a#detailsScopeTab').click()
# wait for the table to load
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//div[@id="ScopeQualification"]//div[@class="t-pagesize-wrapper"]')))

# click on the button to have all rows at once
each_url.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="ScopeQualification"]//div[@class="t-pagesize- 
wrapper"]/a[last()]').click()


# wait for the table loads the new data
class element_css_class_flashed(object):
def __init__(self, locator, css_class):
    self.locator = locator
    self.css_class = css_class
    self.was_on = False

def __call__(self, driver):
    element = driver.find_element(*self.locator)
    if self.css_class in element.get_attribute("class"):
        self.was_on = True
    elif self.was_on:
        return element
    else:
        return False

try:
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 3)
element = wait.until(element_css_class_flashed(
    (By.XPATH, '//div[@id="ScopeQualification"]//div[@class="t-status"]/a'), 
    "t-loading"))
except:
# most likely the loading was too fast to detect
pass

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
table = soup.select_one('div#ScopeQualification table')
all_rows = table.find_all('tr')
header_row = all_rows[0]
rows = all_rows[1:-1]

data = [[col.text for col in header_row.find_all('th')]]
for row in rows:
data_row = []
for col in row.find_all('td'):
    data_row.append(col.text)
data.append(data_row)

print(data)
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but each_url is a string is it not? Why would the string have the  function on it? Wouldn't this  be coming from the driver?

Comment: sorry i don't understand

Comment: for each_url in course_links_file <- this assigns each line to the variable each_url (a string)

Your error states that each_url doesn't have a function on it called 'find_element_by_css_selector',  which it doesn't because it is a string (str)
"'str' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'"